# How to install iOS app if UDID is set up?

Tags: ios, udid

Someone I know created an app, i'd like to try on my iOS device. They have added my devices UDID and as i understand it, provided i can handle the installation, it should run ok.

They have given me a URL in the format of

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://<url>app.plist
```

But, as expected, when pasted inside the browser, it is not being understood.

Should I ask for more information? Should i somehow follow this url, perhaps via iTunes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should work without problems - iOS devices should be able to understand it. Don't try to use it from your desktop. However, it might be impossible to write it into Safari's address bar.

If that's is the case, create a simple redirect HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple redirect</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=PLIST_URL'">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Also make sure the URL parameter is properly encoded.

Answer (score 1):

First option:

They should give you an IPA file and the provisioning profile they used with the IPA. You should install the provisioning profile on your device and then the IPA. I think both can be done via iTunes. The provisioning profile can also be installed via the iPhone configuration tool (available somewhere in the iOS developer center).

Second option:

Using [testflight](https://testflightapp.com/) or a similar service, once you both have accounts, the developer simply uploads the IPA to testflight and you get a link, which you can use from your device. (Strictly speaking, testflight just packages the first option in a nice, user-friendly way.)